# Glycogen vs cellulose-curvature of glycogen molecule?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, organic-chemistry

I was wondering if anyone knows what the degree of curvature is or bond angle between the $\alpha$ glucose molecules in glycogen is. I know that glycogen/amylose/amylopectin have a general curved backbone (as well as branches in glycogen and amylopectin). This is a consequence of the 1,4-glycosidic bond between $\alpha$ glucose molecules. On the other hand cellulose has straight molceules, which is a consequnce of the 1,4-glycosiodic bond between $\beta$ molecules with alternating orientation. However I cannot find anywhere what the degree of this curvature is in glycogen backbone, or the bond angle between molecules in $\alpha$ 1,4-glycosidic bond?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question. Here, the question actually comes down to how the bond actually looks *vs* how we depict the bond. In detail, see this image of maltose from [here](http://kandacebiologyblog.blogspot.in/2010_10_01_archive.html?m=1):

[image: maltose]

Pay attention to the geometry of the glycosidic bond. From how it is depicted, one would conclude that it is straight in geometry. But how it actually looks is like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maltose):

[image: maltose actual]

Now, the obvious conclusion is that the glycosidic bond does have an angle.

Now, with introduction over, lets come to the main point. After searching a lot, I found the value of this angle. It is 109°, much closer to the general tetrahedral angle ([109.5°](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedral_molecular_geometry)) of sp<sup>3</sup> hybridized oxygen atom (deviation could be due to steric hindrance). See [this](https://freezingblue.com/flashcards/print_preview.cgi?cardsetID=158032) article:

> [image: amylose and amylopectin]
>
> 300 alpha-glucose units, bonded by $\alpha$-1,4 glycosidic linkages, making a 109 degree angle between 2 C-O bonds
> causing the polymer to twist into a helix. -OH group of C<sub>2</sub> projects out into the middle and form H bonds with each other, stabilising the shape.

Yes, the glucose molecules in amylose form intermolecular hydrogen bonds which stabilize the molecule. See [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20120114225823/http://www.lsbu.ac.uk/water/hysta.html) article and in the diagram, notice that the hydrogen bond is formed between adjacent glucose units (to the left and right of the glycosidic oxygen atom):

> [image: amylose h-bonds]
>
> Although the $\alpha$-(1$\rightarrow$4) links are capable of relatively free rotation around the ($\Phi$) phi and ($\Psi$) psi torsions, hydrogen bonding between the O3' and O2 oxygen atoms of sequential residues tends to encourage a helical conformation. These helical structures are relatively stiff and may present contiguous hydrophobic surfaces.